# C++ 11 equivalent of java.util.ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: c++11, dictionary, concurrency, stl, containers

I find myself constantly writing Mutex code in order to synchronize read/write access to a std::unordered_map and other containers so that I can use them as I do java.util.concurrent containers. I was about to start writing a wrapper to encapsulate the Mutex, but I would rather use a well tested library so I don't stuff up the threading.

Is there such a library?

Comment: facebook folly, it offers an AtomicHashMap. https://github.com/facebook/folly?source=cr

Comment: Hmm, its better to have the mutex in the class that has the map and protect reads and writes with shared mutex than wrapping up the map.

Comment: Facebook folly doesn't allow you to delete map elements/free memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel produced a library called [Threading Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) which has two such things: concurrent_hash_map and concurrent_unordered_map.  They have slightly different [characteristics](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm), but one or the other will probably suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, That looks good. Unfortunately it's GPL, which is not compatible with the commercial project I'm working on.

Comment: That's not really so--check out http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/faq/10 -  TBB is dual-licensed, so if you need or want a commercial license rather than GPL, it's available.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: They aren't quite the same. The TBB map doesn't support concurrent erasure unlike the java one.

Answer (score 1):

[Folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) has an `AtomicHashmap` implementation. The major limitation is that you can only use `int32` or `int64` keys. Check the documentation [here](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/AtomicHashMap.md) (specially the Limitation section)