# C++ Hierarchical Data Structure for Multi-Threaded Application

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures

I am looking for a hierarchical data-structure for use in a C++ application that is well-suited to frequent read/write operations from multiple threads.

I intend to use this data-structure for multiple purposes, but perhaps the most indicative use-case would be a scenegraph implementation in which nodes can contain terminal properties as well as child nodes. In this usage, a function on the main thread would repeatedly traverse the node tree and render the scene to an OpenGL context while another another thread performs periodic changes to the scene's properties.

Ignoring the multi-threaded read/write access for a moment, I can think of numerous custom and out-of-the-box ways of achieving this functionality (some more efficient than others).

JSON is one solution. Though, in a C++ context, I would prefer to circumvent the large number of lexical casts that come with storing terminal properties as strings. In my case, using a boost::variant for my generic property type would be preferable.

But of course my main concern is the multi-threading issue.

A few possible solutions that come to mind are:

- [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/cpp/)
- [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) / [Parallel Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/index.html)
- A custom implementation using locking mechanisms for each node in the hierarchy

Does anyone have any thoughts on an efficient solution? 
Would a database solution such as MongoDB be fast enough for use in a scenegraph (60 fps refresh, etc)? Would the (Parallel) Boost Graph Library be of any use here? Are there other tools I'm not aware of that might be useful here? I know OpenScenegraph offers some sort of multi-threaded support, but I'm hoping to find a more generalized solution (and one that doesn't come with all the other overhead of that library).

Comment: You won't get a speed up if you do it like that.  What you want to do is have two copies of your graph.  Copying things is fast if you organise your structure well.  At the end once you've finished writing, you make a copy and give that to your threads to process (read), whilst your writer/editor thread starts processing a new copy/frame.   This will avoid the constant lock contention a reader/writer solution entails.

Comment: Have a look [at this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118889/c-11-equivalent-of-java-util-concurrenthashmap).

Comment: Thanks Robinson - I'm not sure I understand the model you describe. Can you elaborate? When the writer finishes, does it overwrite a persistent copy that is then accessed by the readers (this would require a lock, right)? Or does the writer distribute a fresh copy to each reader? If I'm understanding correctly, this seems like it would only work with a single writer, correct?

Comment: Thanks sparc_spread - I'd come across that post (and should have included TBB in my list above). Would this approach be suitable for frequent read/write operations from multiple threads as would be needed to draw a scenegraph?

Comment: It depends on the specifics of your simulation.  If it's OK for the writer to carry on making copies as time goes on, it can queue them up if it's faster than the readers (to some limit, at which point it blocks).  If you only ever want it to be 1 frame behind, your max queue length is 1 and the writer waits for all readers to finish before posting its new copy.  The point is to avoid having to lock every time you access a node.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification. I can see how this is preferable to a lock-based approach in many ways, but would this efficiency hold if the data-structure were quite large (and therefore required lots of copying)?